# while loop still loops one more time even though condition is false

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

My code seems to be stuck in this while loop forever:

```
array = []
b = 1
while b != 0:
    b = int(input("please enter whole numbers "))
    array += [b]
print (array)
```

The meaning of the code is to put user inputs into an array and stop when user enter 0. I don't know why the loop manages to continue the code even though the condition is false. I thought as long as condition is false, python will stop right there!

I keep getting `0` as an element in the array when I don't want it to be in.

Comment: While loops only stop when the program gets back to the top of the loop to examine the condition you have set (you used `b!=0`). Before it gets back to the top it has to go through all the statements to the bottom, which in your case includes `array += [b]`. This means that `b` will be `0` on the last time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified magamongo's answer a little in order to not use break, but you could also use it as in quamrana's answer:

```
array = []
b = 1
while b != 0:
    b = int(input("please enter whole numbers "))
    array += [b]
array = array[:-1]
print(array)
```

Comment: thank you, yes I thought of using break but my teacher hasnt taught it yet and it makes much more sense using basic tools like you did here. I never thought of that. thank you one more.

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe a break is useful when there is a lot of operations before the loop ends. But if you have the same computation I think that preventing break statement is better, because they break the flow of execution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use your own exit condition and not rely on the `while` statement itself stopping:

```
array = []

while True:   # never exit here
    b = int(input("please enter whole numbers "))
    if b == 0:
        break    # exit the loop here
    array += [b]
print (array)
```

Comment: thank you so much for getting back at me so fast, you are of great help

Answer (score 0):

"break" helps you to do that.

```py
array=[1]
while array[-1] != 0:
  b = int(input("please enter a whole number"))
  array += [b]
  if array[-1] == 0:
    print(array[1:-1])
    break
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You seem to have added a `1` at the start *and* a `0` at the end of the array. The OP certainly doesn't want the `0` at the end.

Comment: OK, then put "print(array[1:-1])" in place of "print(array)"